# loading external json object from external file

Tags: javascript, json, import, external

I've seen this question asked several times, but the solutions aren't working. At [this](http://ec2-107-21-104-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com/v/1/financial-organization/accel-partners.js) link, there's a nameless JSON object. I'm trying to get access to the data in the object. This is what I've tried so far:

[image: chrome console attempts]

$.getJSON is returning different errors. I read that adding "&callback=?" to the url would stop the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error, which worked, but then I ran into the "Unexpected token :" error. The JSON data looks correct to me, though.

I also tried doing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-latest.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
var jsondata = {}

$(document).ready(function() {
    url = //removed to prevent line wrap
    $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?",
       function(data) { jsondata = data; } );
});
</script>
```

It produced the same unexpected token error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate your URL path from your parameters with a `?`, not a `&`. The server doesn't like your request because it can't find a resource named `accel-partners.js&callback=`. It does, however, know of a resource named `accel-partners.js`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    url = //removed to prevent line wrap
    var callback = ???; // Make sure to define your callback here
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=" + callback,
       function(data) { jsondata = data; } );
});
```

Comment: Dang it. Thanks. I didn't catch that typo for over 30 minutes.